# AuthenticationFailedException Username and Password not accepted when using Spring Email

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to send an email to the user when he makes a reservation. To do this, I decided to try sending an email to two of my emails. I watched several tutorials and decided to do it as shown in the videos, but something didn't work out

I add this dependency in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

And this in application.properties

I will swap my password with 'XXXXX' (this is the email password)

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=cinemawebkatrina@gmail.com
spring.mail.password=xxxxxxx
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

And this is my java code

```
SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
message.setFrom("cinemawebkatrina@gmail.com");
message.setTo("ppikursov19@gmail.com");
message.setSubject("Test");
message.setText(strMessage);
emailSender.send(message);
```

Do you have any idea what I did wrong and why I can't send an email. I saw this error 'Username and Password not accepted'.

> 2021-04-04 15:45:57.737 ERROR 6532 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet] : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.mail.MailAuthenticationException: Authentication failed; nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8 support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials f17sm1431874lfq.175 - gsmtp ] with root cause

In my `application.properties` file, do I need to use the email's username and password?

Comment: The error is -
2021-04-04 15:45:57.737 ERROR 6532 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.mail.MailAuthenticationException: Authentication failed; nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials f17sm1431874lfq.175 - gsmtp
] with root cause

Comment: *do I need to use the email's username and password* **Yes**